# Recover data from server with "broken disk" Raid1

Tags: linux, raid-1

One of the drives (sdc) on the server hosted on hetzner has gone broken and I cannot mount the drives to backup the data, following is the df, fdisk, mdstat, examine outputs

All i want to do is recover the data from md3, md2 both of which are gone inactive.

df:

```
root@rescue ~ # df -H
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                17G   24M   17G   1% /
udev                  17G     0   17G   0% /dev
IP:/nfs  265G  129G  123G  52% /root/.oldroot/nfs
aufs                  17G   24M   17G   1% /
tmpfs                3.4G  320k  3.4G   1% /run
tmpfs                5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                6.8G     0  6.8G   0% /run/shm
```

Fdisk:

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486401 cylinders, total 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0009b1c1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    33556480    16777216+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2        33558528    34607104      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3        34609152  1443194880   704292864+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda4      1443196928  5738164222  2147483647+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sda5      1443198976  5736069120  2146435072+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.8 GB, 4000787030016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486401 cylinders, total 7814037168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003f2f6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    33556480    16777216+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2        33558528    34607104      524288+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3        34609152  1443194880   704292864+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb4      1443196928  5738164222  2147483647+   f  W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5      1443198976  5736069120  2146435072+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md1: 536 MB, 536805376 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 131056 cylinders, total 1048448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

Here is the mdstat

```
root@rescue ~ # cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md3 : inactive sda5[0](S) sdb5[1](S)
      4292870128 blocks super 1.0

md2 : inactive sda3[0](S) sdb3[1](S)
      1408585712 blocks super 1.0

md1 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      524224 blocks super 1.0 [3/2] [UU_]

md0 : inactive sda1[0](S) sdb1[1](S)
      33554416 blocks super 1.0
```

md2, md3, md0 are showing as inactive status

Following is the mdadm --examine

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sda1/ /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sda1/: Not a directory
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : c587590d:f7caa7e8:55ca8b47:15eaf9dc
           Name : rescue:0  (local to host rescue)
  Creation Time : Mon Dec  8 20:43:21 2014
     Raid Level : raid0
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 33554416 (16.00 GiB 17.18 GB)
   Super Offset : 33554416 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 36bf3e8a:2b51ef66:b3b0aed6:f988ddc2

    Update Time : Mon Dec  8 20:43:21 2014
       Checksum : 8f266e36 - correct
         Events : 0

     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
mdadm: cannot open /dev/sdc1: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like /dev/sda is the culprit here.

I would firstly take a backup of the disk which isn't dead (/dev/sdb), and store it somewhere safe.

`dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/someplace/safe/sdb1.img`

Do that for each of the partitions.  Once you are happy that you have a backup, you'll need to release the device using `mdadm -S mdX` where X is the raid devce you want to bring down.

Now you should be able to mount the device using `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/...` where ... is a directory you have created for the mountpoint.

Good luck.

Comment: btw if i examine sda5 I get following:

mdadm --examine /dev/sda5
    /dev/sda5:
              Magic : a92b4efc
            Version : 1.0
        Feature Map : 0x0
         Array UUID : 2bd2d905:52cad4b4:a1334590:7327d806
               Name : rescue:3  (local to host rescue)
      Creation Time : Mon Dec  8 20:43:22 2014
         Raid Level : raid0
       Raid Devices : 3

Comment: Perhaps the partition `/dev/sda1` is trashed if `/dev/sda5` is readable? Have you attempted to mount it to see if the data is there?

Comment: If i stop md2
mdadm -S /dev/md2
and try to mount 
mount -o ro /dev/sda3 /mnt/md2sda3

I get following error mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'